# GRASS r.sun returns "ERROR: insol_time and incidout are incompatible options"

Tags: grass-gis, dem, qgis-3, qgis-grass-plugin, grass.script

I'm trying to measure irradiance on a DEM using the r.sun tool in QGIS 3.6. I have grids for the elevation (EPSG:32735 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 35S), the slope and aspect (EPSG:4326 - WGS 84). I've tried to ensure they are in the proper coordinate systems asked for [here](http://file:///Applications/QGIS3.6.app/Contents/MacOS/grass/docs/html/r.sun.html).

However, every time I run it, I get the following list of red errors in the log:

```
*ERROR: insol_time and incidout are incompatible options

ERROR: Raster map incidoutce7a2d761eb742ac87d7519caff9005a not found

ERROR: Raster map or group incidoutce7a2d761eb742ac87d7519caff9005a not found

ERROR: Raster map beam_radce7a2d761eb742ac87d7519caff9005a not found

ERROR: Raster map or group beam_radce7a2d761eb742ac87d7519caff9005a not found

ERROR: Raster map insol_timece7a2d761eb742ac87d7519caff9005a not found

ERROR: Raster map or group insol_timece7a2d761eb742ac87d7519caff9005a not found

ERROR: Raster map diff_radce7a2d761eb742ac87d7519caff9005a not found

ERROR: Raster map or group diff_radce7a2d761eb742ac87d7519caff9005a not found

ERROR: Raster map refl_radce7a2d761eb742ac87d7519caff9005a not found

ERROR: Raster map or group refl_radce7a2d761eb742ac87d7519caff9005a not found

ERROR: Raster map glob_radce7a2d761eb742ac87d7519caff9005a not found

ERROR: Raster map or group glob_radce7a2d761eb742ac87d7519caff9005a not found*
```

Then no output map is generated. I've tried running it in an older version of QGIS (2.18), but the whole program just crashes.

It looks like someone has reported a bug about the first line of the error [here](https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21637). But wondering if there's anything I'm doing wrong as I'm new to using GRASS.